What is this FPS game?
I saw this game in a YouTube video and grabbed a few screenshots and would love to know what game it is. Thank you kindly!



Please provide a link to the video

was thinking Combat Master fpr the airbrushed guns, but the itallic font is wrong.

overwatch 2, most likely?
